# Display update notification messages like 'What's New'

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, admin, updates

I am about to push out a new update for my plugin. I've used a few functions only available to WordPress 3.8, which is fine because I want to support the latest version.

How do I display a message to the user before they update the plugin with a list of *What's New*, or just a general warning that WordPress 3.8 is required to run the latest version of the plugin?

I have attached a screenshot of where I'd like the message to display. Is this something that is displayed based on what you put in the change log of your `readme.txt` in trunk?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hook into [`in_plugin_update_message-{$file}`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-admin/includes/update.php#L323).

For the above plugin, the according code looks as follows:

```
add_action('admin_menu', array($this,'admin_menu'), 11);
function admin_menu()
{
    global $pagenow;

    if( $pagenow == 'plugins.php' )
    {
        $hook = apply_filters('acf/get_info', 'hook');

        add_action( 'in_plugin_update_message-' . $hook, array($this, 'in_plugin_update_message'), 10, 2 );
    }
}

function in_plugin_update_message( $plugin_data, $r )
{
    $version = apply_filters('acf/get_info', 'version');
    $readme = wp_remote_fopen( 'http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/advanced-custom-fields/trunk/readme.txt' );
    $regexp = '/== Changelog ==(.*)= ' . $version . ' =/sm';
    $o = '';

    if( !$readme )
    {
        return;
    }

    preg_match( $regexp, $readme, $matches );

    if( ! isset($matches[1]) )
    {
        return;
    }

    $changelog = explode('*', $matches[1]);
    array_shift( $changelog );

    if( !empty($changelog) )
    {
        $o .= '<div class="acf-plugin-update-info">';
        $o .= '<h3>' . __("What's new", 'acf') . '</h3>';
        $o .= '<ul>';

        foreach( $changelog as $item )
        {
            $item = explode('http', $item);

            $o .= '<li>' . $item[0];

            if( isset($item[1]) )
            {
                $o .= '<a href="http' . $item[1] . '" target="_blank">' . __("credits",'acf') . '</a>';
            }

            $o .= '</li>';


        }

        $o .= '</ul></div>';
    }

    echo $o;
}
```

<sub>Ad: [Here](https://github.com/intermedi8/IM8-Box-Hide/blob/master/im8-box-hide.php#L476) is how I did this for a plugin I'm involved in.</sub>